# Opening a folder creates an icon on the desktop

Tags: 14.04, icons

I use Ubuntu 14.04. and have the problem that if I open a folder, an icon appears on the desktop. After working the whole day, I have hundreds of icons, which is really irritating.

I also have two folders which stay steady on the desktop. I don't know what is causing this issue. How can I remove those icons permanently?

As you can see when I open the folder at `130.xx.xx.xx` an icon will be created on the desktop.

#### Desktop screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Kindly take a screenshot of your desktop and upload the image on imgur.com then provide us with the link here. We need to see what you're saying exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I meant, on my Desktop one icon appears of the folder which I opened before on my Computer. So I have a directly link to the directory of this folder. Later I will give you a picture of an example.

Comment: Cool @Elly. I'm waiting for a screenshot of that desktop. Maybe I can be able to help you...

Comment: Here is the picture of a simple example. As you can see when I open the folder "<name>at130.xx.xx.xx." an icon will be created on the desktop. The folders on the top are some I couldn't remove yet. This issue happened from one to another day and I don't understand why?... 

http://imgur.com/Tf8sKlg

(sorry format of the picture was not supported!)

Comment: Your home directory seems to be on a network drive. What is the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm: The output is

      XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"
      XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
      XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Vorlagen"
      XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Öffentlich"
      XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Dokumente"
      XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Musik"
      XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Bilder"
      XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Answer (score 1):

One can hide and unhide network-servers / shares using `gsettings`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop network-icon-visible false
```

Refer [here](https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/category/gnome-shell-components/desktop/) for reference

Comment: Thank you! It hides the permanent icons with nemo: 

`gsettings set org.nemo.desktop computer-icon-visible false`

But the the network icons nevertheless come over and over again.